# Switch between open application in windows using application name

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, alt-tab

Is there any way to switch applications in Windows by typing the application name?

When I have many applications open I find <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> switching to be slower. Is there an alternate way to switch between applications?

Comment: use this alternative tool: http://www.ntwind.com/software/vistaswitcher.html

Answer (score 6):

You can use (Windows 7)

```
Ctrl-Shift-Esc    - Starts task manager (Activate Applications Tab if necessary)
Start typing      - selects an application (by window caption)
Enter (or ALT-S)  - activates the application
```

---

Just tried it at home (Windows 8.1) and the process is a bit more convoluted unfortunately

```
Ctrl-Shift-Esc    - Starts task manager (Activate Applications Tab if necessary)
Start typing      - selects an application (by window caption)
Right Arrow       - Expands the process
Right Arrow       - Navigates to the window of the process
Enter             - activates the application
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but Enter doesn't activate the application.. !

Comment: ALT-S will switch to the one highlighted

Comment: Don't know why not, it does on my system *(switch to is the default option)* but the ALT-S option provided by Jon is a valid alternative.

Comment: The Windows 8.1 method also works in Windows 10. But it's worth noting it doesn't seem to work for apps that can have a lot of seperate processes running like conemu or firefox.

Comment: Not working for me on Windows 7.

Comment: @Ghos3t - wich part of the 3 steps is not working? You have the Applications tab active? Did you try ALT-S io Enter?

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers hitting Alt+S just takes the focus to the file menu and hitting enter does nothing for me. I have found a better solution though, it's a software called Switcheroo(http://www.switcheroo.io/).

Comment: @Ghos3t - You'll have to use key accelarator assigned to the Switch To button that applies to your language. I assume your default language is not set to English. I'm not averse to installing 3th party apps, I'm using AutoHotkey myself but my aim here was to provide an out of the box solution.

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for a application with the same functionality that you mentioned and I found this software called [Switcheroo](https://github.com/kvakulo/Switcheroo), it works exactly as I wanted. It is open source and it is available as a portable download.

A short description about this software:-

Switcheroo allows you to quickly switch to any window by typing in just a few characters of its title. It's inspired by Emacs's IDO mode buffer switching and JetBrains' ReSharper.

The default key binding for Switcheroo is Alt + Space. Pressing this key combination will bring up the Switcheroo window, which lists the titles of every open window. Typing filters the list. Press Enter to switch to the selected window. Press Ctrl + Enter to close the selected window.

Comment: I like this answer, but (even though it might seem redundant) you might want to add how it addresses the original question (i.e. it allows text input, searching, etc.) and maybe even a short blurb about the software itself. Not everyone is going to click the link automatically, unfortunately. =P

Answer (score 0):

No there is no way to write the name of application to switch between applications.

Alternate way is to simply go to the taskbar and select the application.